# Clojure: How to do basic recursion?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a simple recursive function in clojure, on tryclj.com.

```
(defn sum-to-n [n]
  (if (<= n 0) n
      (+ n (sum-to-n (- n 1)))))
```

Calling the function by typing `(sum-to-n 4)` causes an exception to be raised:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'sandbox16265/sum-to-n

It looks like you can't even make a recursive function call. But, curiously, even calling `(sum-to-n 0)`, which shouldn't trigger the recursive function call, throws the same exception. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: tryclj.com randomly clears the state of all definitions, you just need to re-enter your definition. Also, it's better to use `recur` when possible (and it is applicable here), but that has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: Your function works for me in a [lein repl](http://leiningen.org/). tryclj is probably trying to avoid malicious recursion.

Comment: Works fine for me with tryclj.com. But I know the problem: sometimes basic things seem to randomly not work in tryclj.com.

Comment: @sloth I just copied and pasted it now and it worked

Comment: @mikeyhew I once had the problem that maps `(def m {:foo :bar}` I created didn't work in functions `(some-function m)`. I simply use a local REPL most of the time now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tryclj.com has an about link that explains it:

> Also, the interpreter deletes the data that you enter if you define too many things, or after 15 minutes.

In case other things don't work as expected you should know that it uses [Clojail](https://github.com/Raynes/clojail), a sandboxing library that imposes lots of restrictions on what you can do. Like commenters have said, this works fine in a Clojure repl or a compiled program.

Other things you should check out: `recur` for tail recursion to avoid blowing your stack, `dec`/`inc`, `pos?`, `zero?` and `neg?` for more readable checks. Of course, you know this particular function doesn't need to be recursive. You could write it as:

```
 (defn sum-to-n [n]
     (quot (* n (inc n)) 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn sum-to-n [n]
    (if (= n 1)
        n
        (+ n (sum-to-n (dec n)))))
```

This code works. Try and see.

Answer (score 0):

It's a try-clj problem. I don't know exactly what.

> (defn f[] 1)
>
> ## 'sandbox8136/f
>
> (f)
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'sandbox8136/f